# How to communicate if stack allocated references are allowed as argument?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, documentation, code-documentation

I am looking for a standard way to tell the user of a C++ API whether a constructor (or method) accepts objects allocated on the stack as valid arguments. Is there a pattern (e.g. a special constructor/method signature) that tells *no stack objects here*/*stack objects are okay here*? Is there a common sense for a default assumption if stack objects are allowed when not otherwise documented?

Illustration of the problem: When a class `Vector6D` has a constructor `Vector6D(const Vector3D& upper, const Vector3D& lower)` there are at least two ways the class could be implemented:

a) Copy the elements of the two vectors in the constructor and forget about the `Vector3D` instances.

b) Aggregate the `Vector3D` instances in the `Vector6D` and keep using the references for subsequent method calls.

For a) it doesn't matter where the `Vector3D` instances are allocated. For b) if the `Vector3D` instances are allocated on the stack, the implementation stops working when the stack frame vanishes.

So without looking at the implementation or a documentation the user can't decide what to do.

**edit:** The context is an embedded software project and I am not allowed to use the STL, exceptions, boost etc.

Comment: Why are you using a class or function if you don't know what it does (i.e. you haven't looked at the documentation)? Also, there are perfectly valid use cases for passing objects on the stack to a class which stores a reference to it.

Comment: A function shouldn't care where its arguments come from unless part of its contractual behavior is taking ownership of heap objects. In these cases, pass by `std::unique_ptr<T>` (or a reference to one for optional ownership transfer) or `std::shared_ptr<T>` for sharing ownership.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley Actually I am writing an API and I am asking what options there are to tell my users what is allowed and what not. I could write this in prose to every single method, but there might be a better option.

Comment: @Alexander: Why would you want to disallow stack allocated objects though? The example you present is not a valid use case. Why shouldn't I be able to have two `Vector3D` objects with the same lifetime as my `Vector6D` object? Both on the stack.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley: This can happen easily. e.g. there is a class `Filter` holding a `Vector6D` member to do calculations. The `Filter` constructor initializes the `Vector6D` with Vector6Da(Vector3D(1.,2.,3.), Vector3D(4.,5.,6.)). When the constructor is done, the values become illegal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no mechanism in C++ to enforce that a constructor (or other mutating member method) parameter lifetime exceed that of the object.

Only ownership of heap allocated objects, held in and passed via `std::unique_ptr<T>`, `std::shared_ptr<T>`, or similar, can be cleanly expressed and transferred.

**It would be considered bad class design to have ad hoc conventions, unenforced by compilers, hinting that arguments are stored as references.**

You should consider the following general guidelines:

- Cheaply copied types should just be copied.
- Non-copyable types should be heap-allocated and passed/owned via smart pointers.
- Types deemed "too expensive" to copy should be smart pointer allocated as well if they need to be shared persistently with other objects with independent lifetimes.

There are exceptions to this heap-allocation policy when lifetimes aren't arbitrarily controlled by API users, but not in scenarios like you describe above.